# Ember.js commiting parent model with already existing child models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Cheers! For example I have three models:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bars: DS.hasMany('App.Bar', {embedded:'always'}),
  bazes: DS.hasMany('App.Baz', {embedded:'always'})
});

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.belongsTo('App.Foo')
});

App.Baz = DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.belongsTo('App.Foo)
});
```

And adapter mappings like these:

```
App.RESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    this.map('App.Foo', {
      bars:{embedded: 'always'},
      bazes:{embedded: 'always'}
    })
  }
});
```

I'm saving child records first in separated transactions ([github.com/emberjs/data/pull/440](http://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/440)):

```
barTransaction = App.store.transaction();
bar = barTransaction.createRecord(App.Bar);

//later
bazTransaction = App.store.transaction();
baz = bazTransaction.createRecord(App.Baz);

//later
fooTransaction = App.store.transaction();
foo = fooTransaction.createRecord(App.Foo);

//later
foo.get('bars').addObject(bar);
foo.get('bazes').addObject(baz);
fooTransaction.commit();
```

I just want to know if it possible to save parent and all child records with one POST request?
For now it's creating one POST request for every child record separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is with an outdated way of mapping embedded records. This used to happen in the serializer, but is now happening on a map() on the adapter...

You can see the integration test here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/embedded/embedded_saving_test.js#L50

I think something along these lines will work:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bars: DS.hasMany('App.Bar'),
  bazes: DS.hasMany('App.Baz')
});

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.belongsTo('App.Foo')
});

App.Baz = DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.belongsTo('App.Foo')
});

App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({..configs..});

App.Adapter.map('App.Foo', {
  bars:{embedded: 'always'},
  bazes:{embedded: 'always'}
})
```

This should `POST` to the api at: `api.com/foo` and include the `bars` and `bazes`