# How can i save nested models

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a Ember.js project that uses ember data and the RESTAdapter.

My model exists out of questions and possible answers.

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    answers: DS.hasMany('App.Answer'),
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
    question: DS.belongsTo('App.Question'),
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My view is a modal, in which you can create or edit questions and their answers. The questions and possible answers should be saved on hitting the save button, or on uploading an image.

The problem is that the saving procedure is very complicated.

- In order to upload an image of an answer, I need to make sure the answer exists on the server.
- In order to save the answer, I need to make sure the question exists.

Is their a way to tell ember to save the whole Question, with it's answers, at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution might just be a workaround for your problem:

```
DS.RESTadapter.map('App.Question', { answers: {embedded: 'always'} });
```

See for instance: [Ember.js commiting parent model with already existing child models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025618/ember-js-commiting-parent-model-with-already-existing-child-models)

Much more on relationships can be found in the BREAKING CHANGES: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md